How to append header to URLSessionWebSocketTask
I need to append headers to URLSessionWebSocketTask, I did it using URLRequest but don't know if its proper way to do it because I use WSS connection instead of HTTP.
var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask!
    
    lazy var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())

private var urlRequest: URLRequest = {
        var request = URLRequest(url: ApiUrl.socket.url)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "login" : "****",
            "passcode" : "****",
            "host" : "/",
            "accept-version" : "****"
        ]
        return request
    }()

public override init() {
        super.init()
        webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
    }

And also I need to subscribe to event, but can't get what I need to do. You can see screenshot below.


It might be old, but might still be working, why not use their client https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/tree/main ? Or maybe "debug it" to find how they do it?

Can you try this code?
class WebSocketManager: NSObject, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    
    private var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask!
    
    private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
    }()
    
    private var urlRequest: URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: ApiUrl.socket.url)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "login" : "****",
            "passcode" : "****",
            "host" : "/",
            "accept-version" : "****"
        ]
        return request
    }
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
    }
    
    func connect() {
        webSocketTask.resume()
        
    }
    
}

You need to debug more about your problem.
extension WebSocketManager {
    
    func send(message: String) {
        let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(message)
        webSocketTask.send(message) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("WebSocket sending error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func receive() {
        webSocketTask.receive { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("WebSocket receiving error: \(error)")
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case .string(let text):
                    print("Received text: \(text)")
                case .data(let data):
                    print("Received data: \(data)")
                @unknown default:
                    fatalError()
                }
                
                
                self?.receive()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func disconnect() {
        webSocketTask.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }
}


I generally have no idea what operation is subscribe and how to do it with URLSessionWebSocket, I have recently opened StompClientLib to do this but have some issues like its not pinging and it has no spm support. Will be glad if you show me the path where I need to dig. Thanks beforehand!

First you need to find where is the problem in your codes. If you add your codes like I added more success and error cases that will help you.

I don't get any response though, I need to subscribe to RabbitMQ websocket as I show in screenshot above. Therefore, I couldn't get any response from socket.
